# Cannot figure out multiple onmousedown/up and click event in a piece of code

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use multiple click events within a piece of javascript code. I was looking to put a simple practice piece together for now, and was looking at the javascript events page on the w3schools.com website and was looking to do something along the lines of what can be seen at the top of the page (see link) with the Click Me interactive div box.. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp

I've managed to do simple onmousedown and up events to display new text but, I can't figure out how to do multiple click events such as on the w3schools website page. Is an EventListener to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using something like this:

```
var clickCount = 0;
document.getElementById("box").onclick = function(){
   switch(clickCount){
   case 0:
       this.innerHTML += "Click me again<br />"
       break;
   case 1:
       this.innerHTML += "And again<br />";
       break;
   case 2:
       this.style.display = "none";
       break;
   }
   clickCount++;
};
```

http://codepen.io/idmean/pen/EbHsz